# EXISTS IN query how to?

Tags: mysql

Can someone help me with this, i've got 2 tables

financeaccountcurrencymapping and ownedaccount.

i want to select those financeaccountcurrencymapping whose field legalEntity_id is something.

Here is what i have so far.

```
SELECT 
FROM financeaccountcurrencymapping 
WHERE ownedAccount_id EXISTS IN (
                SELECT id 
                FROM ownedaccount 
                WHERE legalEntity_id = ??);
```

The fields in the table are:

'financeaccountcurrencymapping'

- id
- moneyCurrency
- accountForCash_id
- ownedAccount_id

'ownedaccount'

- id
- name
- legalEntity_id
- assetOrLiability
- assetType
- depositoryType
- liabilityType
- multipleCurrency
- Currency
- description

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would not use EXISTS in this case.  IN alone would work.

```
SELECT 
FROM financeaccountcurrencymapping 
WHERE ownedAccount_id IN (SELECT id FROM ownedaccount WHERE legalEntity_id = ??);
```

Comment: Change from SELECT to DELETE.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT legalEntity_id
FROM financeaccountcurrencymapping 
WHERE ownedAccount_id IN (
                SELECT id 
                FROM ownedaccount 
                WHERE legalEntity_id = ??);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're original query is really close.  You just need to remove the `EXISTS`, like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM financeaccountcurrencymapping 
WHERE ownedAccount_id IN (
                SELECT id 
                FROM ownedaccount 
                WHERE legalEntity_id = ??);
```

Alternatively, you could write this query with a `JOIN` for the same effective result.

```
SELECT f.*
FROM financeaccountcurrencymapping AS f 
INNER JOIN ownedaccount AS o ON (f.id = o.ownedAccount_id) 
WHERE o.legalEntity_id = ??;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanted to use EXISTS or wanted to see an example of how it's used, I think the following would work.  Personally I would probably use IN instead.

```
SELECT 
FROM financeaccountcurrencymapping as f
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT id 
              FROM ownedaccount 
              WHERE f.ownedAccount_id = id AND legalEntity_id = ??);
```

Comment: Instead of SELECT, use DELETE.